# Restart android application with cleared context cache

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I'm having an application that needs to be cleared from the cache and restarted programmatically.

I've tried with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
startActivity(i);
```

But that will not entirely clear all cache as the old context is somehow retrieved.

I've managed to implement an ugly workaround by doing this, but I would be glad if there was another solution to this:

```
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 1122;    
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, mPendingIntentId,
                               mStartActivity,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmMgr =(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// Set the alarm that will invoke and start the activity after we 
//   killed the current process
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+10, mPendingIntent);

// Kill the application process, this will for sure clear up all 
//   memory!
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cleared from the cache" and "old context". Explain exactly what you are seeing and what the problem is. What do you want to happen?

Comment: Do you have singleTask on the Activity tag? it's supossed to work like you described, you receive new intents by overriding ```onNewIntent```

Comment: Ok, so when I start my application the first time, an initialization is done (this is a huge initialization involving several steps and triggers a lot of methods. I haven't been able to fully track the whole initialization). But once I change one of my options that only can be changed by reinitialize the app, that will in fact not do the full initialization if I do a finish() and then start it again with the new option (as I can see some of the triggers of the methods is not run). However, if I kill the process, and then restart the application, the full initialization is done!

Comment: This makes me think that there must be some old data that is not freed up once I do the finish() and start the activity again with startActivity method.